# Grub2win is showing a bunch of errors while trying to dual boot ChromeOS

Tags: windows-11, google-chrome-os, dualboot

I tried to install chromeos using this [guide](https://youtu.be/IUuJIkPssEs?t=334) I did exactly everything except the step at 5:34 because it didn't show for me and continued to the end,when booting to grub2win and trying to start chromeos it shows these errors

```
error: no such device: /chromeos.
error: unknown filesystem.
error: disk `loop,7' not found.
error: you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

I really can't tell whats the problem

Answer (score 0):

The video first watch:
[Dual Boot Chrome OS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OicSb2QpAVk)
works in Windows 11/10/8.1/8/7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144619)